# twitter-bootstrap-rails gem how to make navbar not collapsable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, the navbar is collapsable by default, and that's really annoying. So, how do I remove this feature entirely?

What exactly do I have to put in the bootstrap_and_override.css.less to make it not collapsable?

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect the page with any tool Viz. Firebug and note down the classes,id's produced by bootstrap.
Finally put those in your style sheet and tweak as you wanted, you got your bootstrap changed.